# traefik listens on port 80 and forwards the request to minio console(5000) 404

Tags: traefik

I deployed minio and the console in K8S, used ClusterIP to expose ports 9000 & 5000

Listening for port 80 and 5000 forwarding requests to minio.service(ClusterIP)

Request console all right through port 5000

By requesting the console on port 80, you can see the console, but the request is 404 in the browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIMj3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijvjZ.jpg)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: minio-headless
  labels:
    app: minio-headless
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: server
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
    - name: console
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: minio
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: ingress-route-minio
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - minio
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`minio-console.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.k8s.zszc`)
      priority: 10
      services:
        - kind: Service
          name: minio-headless
          namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
          port: 5000
          responseForwarding:
            flushInterval: 1ms
          scheme: http
          strategy: RoundRobin
          weight: 10
```

traefik access log

```json
{
  "ClientAddr": "192.168.4.250:55485",
  "ClientHost": "192.168.4.250",
  "ClientPort": "55485",
  "ClientUsername": "-",
  "DownstreamContentSize": 19,
  "DownstreamStatus": 404,
  "Duration": 688075,
  "OriginContentSize": 19,
  "OriginDuration": 169976,
  "OriginStatus": 404,
  "Overhead": 518099,
  "RequestAddr": "minio-console.etb-0-0-1.k8s.zszc",
  "RequestContentSize": 0,
  "RequestCount": 1018,
  "RequestHost": "minio-console.etb-0-0-1.k8s.zszc",
  "RequestMethod": "GET",
  "RequestPath": "/api/v1/login",
  "RequestPort": "-",
  "RequestProtocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  "RequestScheme": "http",
  "RetryAttempts": 0,
  "RouterName": "traefik-traefik-dashboard-6e26dcbaf28841493448@kubernetescrd",
  "StartLocal": "2023-01-27T13:20:06.337540015Z",
  "StartUTC": "2023-01-27T13:20:06.337540015Z",
  "entryPointName": "web",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "",
  "time": "2023-01-27T13:20:06Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the request for `/api` is conflicting with rules for the Traefik dashboard. If you look at the access log in your question, we see:

```
  "RouterName": "traefik-traefik-dashboard-6e26dcbaf28841493448@kubernetescrd",
```

If you have installed Traefik from the Helm chart, it installs an `IngressRoute` with the following rules:

```
  - kind: Rule
    match: PathPrefix(`/dashboard`) || PathPrefix(`/api`)
    services:
    - kind: TraefikService
      name: api@internal
```

In theory those are bound only to the `traefik` entrypoint, but it looks like you may have customized your entrypoint configuration.

Take a look at the IngressRoute resource for your Traefik dashboard and ensure that it's not sharing an entrypoint with minio.